# How to add typeahead dynamically and get id of input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js and running into problems. I have this html.

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="element_1" >
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="element_2" >
```

And I create similar input elements dynamically. If i use the below code it works for initial input elements but not for dynamically created elements, and rightly so.

```
$('.typeahead').each(function() {
    $(this).typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'items',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: populateItems(this.id)
    })
});


function populateItems (id) {
    return function findMatches(inp, cb) {
        console.log("id: " + id);  //this is where i am accessing id
    };
};
```

If anybody could help me how should I use this so that typeahead can be registered for all elements created dynamically as well, and at the same time I can get id of active element.

Comment: You need to run the typeahead `each()` function as a callback on whatever function creates the new inputs. Ideally, remove the inner code into a new function and call it from both places.